# Can an android button execute another button then execute its own code?

Tags: java, android

If I have two buttons, A and B, is there a way for button B to first run Button A code then the code defined for button B?  Currently button A and button B work in my code but I realize that button A code needs to always run before button B.

Comment: so why not put code out of button A

Comment: If you want to execute the another button's code then put that another button's code to the function. and call that function before the first button execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
buttonB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              buttonA.requestFocus();
                          buttonA.performClick();
                          //then your buttonB operation
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your answer was perfect and simple.  The response was prompt.  Thank-you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Have a look at @Vbif's response, while this response will get what you need done, it is really not good programming practice. You should separate your logic from you view.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use something like this:

In class definition

```
void funcA() {};
void funcB() {};
```

In OnCreate method

```
buttonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { funcA(); });
buttonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { funcA(); funcB(); });
```